# I am trying to implement calling in a AAD using React and Node.Using Graph API /communication/calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am new to Microsoft Azure and Services and registered an application with Azure. But when I tried implement calling in my Web App through graph API '/commmunication/calls It's saying **App is not registered in our store.** error.

I have provided all the permission listed down in the doc as per the Application permission and also calling the API with Application token and not logged in user token.

I need to implement calling in my app which will trigger teams using graph API and get the call object for further assistance.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the application not being published. I guess because the endpoint is for bots. See this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10845). To solve this, you can register a bot. See [here](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new) and [Build Bot Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot#register-your-web-service-with-the-bot-framework) to get started.